# How do I set a custom crontab file inside project?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

I want to set a crontab file in my project repo so that it is tracked and easy to manage. So, I'd prefer if I could add cron jobs in a file in my project e.g. `/home/user1/project/.crontab` instead of `/var/spool/cron/crontab` or `/etc/crontab`. Is there any way to do this?
Operating system would be ubuntu.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way to make `cron` use a different file. The daemon's files are stored in a location owned by the daemon itself which generally cannot be overridden.

But of course, you can always make sure the file that `cron` reads is identical to yours.

```
crontab < /home/user1/project/.crontab
```

will replace any `cron` schedule for the current user with the contents of the input file.